# which one will be more efficient in searching of a certain type of file?

Tags: c, algorithm, system

Suppose I'm designing a file manager and want to implement searching of a file by its type hypothetically then which one of these methods will be more efficient -

1. use the name of the file and trim the extension of each file.
2. use of specific bytes for the type of file we are searching for example in the case of jpeg images.

> ```
> bytes 0xFF, 0xD8 indicate start of image
>
> bytes 0xFF, 0xD9 indicate end of image
> ```

Comment: Stack Overflow does not usually deal with hypothetical questions. However, it seems clear that making the decision based on a filename would be much faster than opening and looking at data.

Comment: What guarantee do you have for that the filename is actually representative for the type of content in the file?  Does it matter?

Comment: Yes it matters there should not be false positive

Comment: If there should be no false positive the then speed/efficiency is not really relevant. Only option 2 would prevent false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to know it's filename before open it, the name trim option will be probably faster. However, you could have false results with that method if an extension does not match with actual file type.

Doing that way will save you some system calls (open, read, maybe fseek, close).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal being: "search a file by its type" without further limitations you have to do it by checking the actual data.

But you might be OK with some false positives and false negatives. If you are searching for image files by looking for extensions only, you can get "image.jpg?width=1024&height=800" instead of "image.jpg" for an image file, a false negative, or "image.jpg" instead of "image.exe", a false positive.

You can, on the other side, check for the first couple of bytes in the file--most schemes for image data have an individual header. This method has much less points of failure. You can get a false positive if you got a chunk of random data with the first bytes resembling the header of an image file. Possible, but highly unlikely. You can get a false negative if the header got stripped (e.g.: on the transport, somehow, or a bad script that produced the file). Also possible and also unlikely, even more so, if not *much* more.

The small Unix tool `file` does that and once had an easy to parse text-file you could use for you own project. It's nowadays a large folder with several single files that doesn't even gets installed, only in a precompiled form. You can find the folder with the text-files online, at e.g.:  http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/file/saucy/files/head:/magic/Magdir/ The format is described in the manpage `magic(5)` which is also online at e.g.: https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation